# Tricky integral involving Arctan

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to do an integral which arises from another integral that is simple in polar coordinates (so I can work out the answer that way). However I am using cartesian coordinates and trying to see if I get the same answer. The integral (with $G>0$) is,

$$I(G)=4\sqrt{1+G^2}\int_{0}^{G}\text{d} x\,\frac{x \tan^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{G^2-x^2}(1+x^2)}\,.$$

From using polar coordinates on the double integral from which this integral arises I find the result,

$$I(G)=\pi \ln\left(1+G^2\right)\,.$$

Are there any substitutions or tricks I can use to evaluate the integral over $x$ above? I noticed that,

$$I(G)=-2\sqrt{1+G^2}\int_{0}^{G}\text{d} x\,\left(\sqrt{G^2-x^2}\right)'\left(\tan^{-1}(x)\right)'\tan^{-1}(x)\,,$$

where prime denotes differentiation with respect to $x$. I'm not sure if this is useful however -- even integrating by parts I end up with another integral I cannot see a way to solve.

Any hints or tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

Define the function $\mathcal{I}:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}:=4\sqrt{1+a^{2}}\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x\arctan{\left(x\right)}}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}},$$

where the arctangent function may be given by the usual integral representation

$$\arctan{\left(z\right)}:=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{1+y^{2}}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{z}{1+z^{2}t^{2}};~~~\small{z\in\mathbb{R}}.$$

We will independently verify the closed form expression for $\mathcal{I}$ asserted in the OP.

---

Given $a\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\land r\in\mathbb{R}$, we can derive the following integration formula:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(1+r^{2}x^{2}\right)\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{\left(1+a^{2}r^{2}y^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-y^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[x=ay\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{2\left(1+a^{2}r^{2}t\right)\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}};~~~\small{\left[y=\sqrt{t}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{2\left(1+a^{2}r^{2}t\right)\left(1-t\right)\sqrt{\frac{t}{1-t}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{\left(1+u\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{2\left[1+a^{2}r^{2}\left(\frac{u}{1+u}\right)\right]\left(\frac{1}{1+u}\right)\sqrt{u}};~~~\small{\left[t=\frac{u}{1+u}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{2\left[\left(1+u\right)+a^{2}r^{2}u\right]\sqrt{u}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{2\left[1+\left(1+a^{2}r^{2}\right)u\right]\sqrt{u}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}r^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{2\left(1+v\right)\sqrt{v}};~~~\small{\left[u=\frac{v}{1+a^{2}r^{2}}\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}r^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{1+w^{2}};~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{v}=w\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1+a^{2}r^{2}}}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Now, suppose $a\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Expressing the arctangent as an integral, we can rewrite $\mathcal{I}$ as a double integral and change the order of integration to find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}
&=4\sqrt{1+a^{2}}\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x\arctan{\left(x\right)}}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}\\
&=4\sqrt{1+a^{2}}\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{x}{1+x^{2}t^{2}}\\
&=4\sqrt{1+a^{2}}\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{x^{2}}{\left(1+x^{2}t^{2}\right)\left(1+x^{2}\right)\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}\\
&=4\sqrt{1+a^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{2}}{\left(1+x^{2}t^{2}\right)\left(1+x^{2}\right)\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}\\
&=4\sqrt{1+a^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(1-t^{2}\right)}\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(1-t^{2}\right)x^{2}}{\left(1+x^{2}t^{2}\right)\left(1+x^{2}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}\\
&=4\sqrt{1+a^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(1-t^{2}\right)}\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}t^{2}\right)}-\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)}\right]\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}\\
&=4\sqrt{1+a^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(1-t^{2}\right)}\bigg{[}\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(1+t^{2}x^{2}\right)\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}\bigg{]}\\
&=4\sqrt{1+a^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(1-t^{2}\right)}\left[\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1+a^{2}t^{2}}}-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1+a^{2}}}\right]\\
&=2\pi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-\sqrt{1+a^{2}t^{2}}}{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\sqrt{1+a^{2}t^{2}}}.\\
\end{align}$$

This is an elementary integral that can be transformed into an integral of a rational function with the appropriate Euler substitution:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}
&=2\pi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-\sqrt{1+a^{2}t^{2}}}{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\sqrt{1+a^{2}t^{2}}}\\
&=2\pi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{a^{2}\left[\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-\sqrt{1+a^{2}t^{2}}\right]}{\left(a^{2}-a^{2}t^{2}\right)\sqrt{1+a^{2}t^{2}}}\\
&=2\pi\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{a\left[\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-\sqrt{1+u^{2}}\right]}{\left(a^{2}-u^{2}\right)\sqrt{1+u^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[t=a^{-1}u\right]}\\
&=2\pi\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{a\left[\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-\sqrt{1+u^{2}}\right]\left[\sqrt{1+a^{2}}+\sqrt{1+u^{2}}\right]}{\left(a^{2}-u^{2}\right)\left[\sqrt{1+a^{2}}+\sqrt{1+u^{2}}\right]\sqrt{1+u^{2}}}\\
&=2\pi\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{a}{\left[\sqrt{1+a^{2}}+\sqrt{1+u^{2}}\right]\sqrt{1+u^{2}}}\\
&=2\pi\int_{1}^{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{(-1)\left(1+v^{2}\right)}{2v^{2}}\cdot\frac{a}{\left[\sqrt{1+a^{2}}+\left(\frac{1+v^{2}}{2v}\right)\right]\left(\frac{1+v^{2}}{2v}\right)};~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{1+u^{2}}-u=v\right]}\\
&=\pi\int_{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{4a}{v^{2}+2v\sqrt{1+a^{2}}+1}\\
&=\pi\int_{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{4a}{\left(v+\sqrt{1+a^{2}}\right)^{2}-a^{2}}\\
&=\pi\int_{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{4a}{\left(v+\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a\right)\left(v+\sqrt{1+a^{2}}+a\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Note: for $0<a$, we have $0<\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a<1<\sqrt{1+a^{2}}+a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}$.

Setting $c:=\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a\in(0,1)$, we have $a=\frac{1-c^{2}}{2c}\land\sqrt{1+a^{2}}=\frac{1+c^{2}}{2c}$, and we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}
&=\pi\int_{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{4a}{\left(v+\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a\right)\left(v+\sqrt{1+a^{2}}+a\right)}\\
&=\pi\int_{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{4a}{\left(v+\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a\right)\left(v+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}\right)}\\
&=\pi\int_{c}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{4\left(\frac{1-c^{2}}{2c}\right)}{\left(v+c\right)\left(v+c^{-1}\right)}\\
&=\pi\int_{c}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{2\left(1-c^{2}\right)}{\left(v+c\right)\left(1+cv\right)}\\
&=2\pi\int_{c}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\left[\frac{1}{\left(v+c\right)}-\frac{c}{\left(1+cv\right)}\right]\\
&=2\pi\int_{c}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{d}{dv}\left[\ln{\left(v+c\right)}-\ln{\left(1+cv\right)}\right]\\
&=2\pi\int_{c}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{d}{dv}\ln{\left(\frac{v+c}{1+cv}\right)}\\
&=2\pi\left[\ln{\left(1\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{2c}{1+c^{2}}\right)}\right]\\
&=2\pi\left[-\ln{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}}\right)}\right]\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+a^{2}\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

Just as you anticipated!

---